# nuget push to artifactory returns 403 (Forbidden)

Tags: nuget, artifactory

I am trying to push a nuget package to a nuget repo in Artifactory. Here are the commands I have used:

nuget sources Add -Name Artifactory -Source http://myURL/artifactory/api/nuget/"Repo name"

nuget setapiky "api key" -source Artifactory

nuget push "my package" -source Artifactory

and I get "Response status code does not indicate success: 403 (Forbidden)."

I have checked that the api key has all the right to the nuget repo.

The repo is set as:

```
Repository Layout:  nuget-default
Remote Repository URL:  https://www.nuget.org/
```

Could that set up prevent me from adding a nuget package?

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you are trying to push packages to a Artifactory [remote](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/NuGet+Repositories#NuGetRepositories-RemoteRepositories) repository which is ideally not allowed as the remote repositories used to resolve the packages only. You should be able publish packages to a Artifacoty [local](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/NuGet+Repositories#NuGetRepositories-LocalRepositories) repository.